# javascript pass var to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Apologies if this is a stupid beginners question, but I'm stuck.

I have some jquery code to get some HTML from the server, which I then wish to paste in a provided div. The div is set as data-target. So I use the `$($(this).attr('data-target'))` context to find the target div. However in the `.done()` function, I'm no longer in the context and I can't find the target div.

```
$('.popout-button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    targetElem = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
    //request
    $.get("ajax.php", {
        action: "defInfo",
        class: "Cats22"
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            //Dump the data
            //This doesn't work. Can I pass targetElem somehow?
            targetElem.html(data);
        });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try targetElem  = $("#targetelement");

Comment: Use `var targetElem = ...` - that will make the variable local to the `.click()` handler, and accessible from the `.done()` handler because it declared inside the `.click()` handler. Your current code without `var` will make `targetElem` global, which could still work unless that click handler applies to multiple buttons and they are clicked in quick succession before the ajax calls return.

Comment: use `var targetElem = $($(this).attr('data-target'));` - declare it as a local variable

Comment: @nnnnnn I think that was the ticket. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your  `targetElem` at global level i.e. out side the function and then initialize it then I think it will work i.e. you can access it from inside the `done` function

```
var targetElem;
$('.popout-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    targetElem = $($(this).attr('data-target'));

    //request
    $.get("ajax.php", {action: "defInfo", class: "Cats22"})
            .done(function(data) {
                //Dump the data

                //This doesn't work. Can I pass targetElem somehow?
                targetElem.html(data);

            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid dealing with the scopes and access the element from a lower level, you can add an id to your element, or, if you can't (for whatever the reason), you can add a class name dynamically... like this:

```
$($(this).attr('data-target')).addClass('target');
```

Then, just select it again within the done() function like this:

```
var targetElem = $('.target');
targetElem.html(data);
```

Comment: But why would you want to select it again within the `.done()` function when you already have a reference to it that is in scope?

Comment: @nnnnnn Not sure what's going on in the rest of the code, so this is to avoid potential scoping issues. I hear you, no reason why OP's example shouldn't work, but maybe he wants a different approach.